# Domain Name Mapping Using Nameserver

Tags: dns, mapping, cname

I have a website www.example.com that create subdomains for each user like

- user1.example.com
- user2.example.com

Now I need to give a feature to map this subdomain to their own website:

- user1.com
- user2.com

When people come to user1.com the same content of user1.example.com needs to be displays.

How can I do this?
Like user1.com is pointed to nameserver ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com

Answer (score 1):

you can create a CNAME record for user1.com to redirect them to user1.example.com

Add the following DNS entry to user1.com's DNS server:

`@  10800 IN CNAME user1.example.com
www 10800 IN CNAME user1.example.com`

Comment: how it can be set in cpanel?